# Can't identify component

Tags: components

I was disassembling an old CRT monitor and I came across this component, but I've been unable to identify it. Can somebody help me with it?

It was found in the horizontal deflection circuit, next to the flyback converter.a

[image: the unidentified component]

Comment: Could you post a picture of the board that you got it from? The neighboring components might give a clue what kind of part it is.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't take a picture of it right now. Sorry

Comment: Just tear its skirt to reveal the hard core and the wires.

Comment: @hkBattousai, <http://i.imgur.com/5qZ2YB9.jpg>. As you can see there's an inductor there, but the top part looks like a transformer.

Comment: Mmm. Look at that Litz....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an inductor, probably made by LG (or at least a clone of a part originally made by LG).

I'd hazard a guess that the -104- in the part marking could mean its 100uH maybe ...

Did you find it in the horizontal deflection circuit?

Comment: Yes, next to the flyback converter. I thought it was an inductor, but I was not sure.